# Freewall.js: Mobile Bug, Object vanishes

Tags: jquery, css, freewalljs

https://codepen.io/bobbygee/pen/GRJLmJX

I have a 2x1 item that vanishes in the mobile view.

```
 cellW: 300,
 cellH: 300,
```

It must have to do with the Cell Width or Height.
Does anyone have advice how to fix this?

Thanks.